# Android ArrayList<String[]> to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json

I need my app to send an `ArrayList<String[]>` to php, I have this to call the service:

```
ArrayList<String[]> Items = new ArrayList<String[]>();
(...)
JSONObject JSONSend= new JSONObject();
JSONSend.put("Items", Items );

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVICE);
post.setHeader("json", JSONSend.toString());
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JSONSend.toString());
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(post);
```

and on the PHP service:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
$Items = $json->{'Items'};
error_log($Items);
```

and the php is returning this:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@413e2fd0, [Ljava.lang.String;@413a2940, [Ljava.lang.String;@4139df18, [Ljava.lang.String;@4141b5b0, [Ljava.lang.String;@413931c8, [Ljava.lang.String;@41348b40, [Ljava.lang.String;@41393928]
```

The type of the $ServMade is string, so how can I take care of the data as an array on php? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following when generating json string in android:

```
JSONObject JSONSend= new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja = null;
JSONArray tmp = new JSONArray();
for(String s[] : Items){
    ja = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length; i++)
        ja.put(s[i]);
    tmp.put(ja);
}
JSONSend.put("Items", tmp);
```

Comment: i used "JSONSend.put("Items", tmp));" instead and it's working as i wanted, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that You call .toString() (within Java) on an array of strings (String[]) that while NOT overrided returns exactly what You get in the JSON: [Ljava.lang.String;@413e2fd0].

Don't know exactly the JSONObject but I guess You should transform the `ArrayList<String[]>` (so the array of arrays of strings) to something different for JSONObject to handle it correctly.

Also, in PHP, You do not have to call `$Items = $json->{'Items'};` - it is okay to call `$Items = $json->Items;`.

Comment: @oneilse14 He directly does not, but i gues that JSONObject::put does.